# Will the nvidia-experimental-310 be packaged for 12.10 (quantal)?

Tags: nvidia, 12.10

Nothing much to add outside the title. The package is currently available for 12.04, but not 12.10.

Comment: It best to be patient - its being prepared. http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/nvidia-settings-experimental-310 - I'll close this for the moment.

Comment: This is quite old already. There's still no package. Can we just use the package from 12.04 or will that make problems?

Comment: I just saw the drivers are in quantal-proposed. So I guess we'll have them soon enough.